# GitHub won't let me push

Tags: git, github, push

Here is what I have done:

Jaspernetwork:~ Jasper$ cd ~/GitHubHelloWorld
Jaspernetwork:GitHubHelloWorld Jasper$ ls
README.md   Readme.txt
Jaspernetwork:GitHubHelloWorld Jasper$ cat < Readme.txt
Jaspernetwork:GitHubHelloWorld Jasper$ git push
warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value is changing in
Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message
and maintain the current behavior after the default changes, use:

git config --global push.default matching

To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:

git config --global push.default simple

When push.default is set to 'matching', git will push local branches
to the remote branches that already exist with the same name.

In Git 2.0, Git will default to the more conservative 'simple'
behavior, which only pushes the current branch to the corresponding
remote branch that 'git pull' uses to update the current branch.

See 'git help config' and search for 'push.default' for further information.
(the 'simple' mode was introduced in Git 1.7.11. Use the similar mode
'current' instead of 'simple' if you sometimes use older versions of Git)

To https://github.com/Napoleon1769/HelloWorld.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Napoleon1769/HelloWorld.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
Jaspernetwork:GitHubHelloWorld Jasper$

I then pulled and then committed however the following response came up:

Jaspernetwork:GitHubHelloWorld Jasper$ git pull
You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists).
Please, commit your changes before you can merge.
Jaspernetwork:GitHubHelloWorld Jasper$ git commit

the commit.

It looks like you may be committing a merge.
If this is not correct, please remove the file
.git/MERGE_HEAD
and try again.
Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
 with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
On branch master
All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.

Changes to be committed:
new file:   README.md
~
~                    `enter code here`
~
~
~
-- INSERT --

Comment: Do git push origin master OR git config --global push.default simple to make git push working

Comment: I tried that it can up with the same response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the message that you quote suggests, you could do `git pull` before pushing. This will ensure that your checkout knows of all commits on the repository.

Comment: I have already pulled and it says i need to commit so i type git commit and then i can type in a comment for some reason:

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are now in the middle of a merge. You must indeed commit it before pushing. Assuming you did now complete the merge and commit, does `git push` still fail?

Comment: how do i do a merge: if i put git status:

Comment: i get:Jaspernetwork:GitHubHelloWorld Jasper$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
Jaspernetwork:GitHubHelloWorld Jasper$ git merge Readme.txt
merge: Readme.txt - not something we can merge
Jaspernetwork:GitHubHelloWorld Jasper$

Comment: Well, `git-merge` doesn't take a file name as its argument, but rather a commit. But this probably isn't relevant; it would be helpful if you could show us the output of `git pull`, and then, if it doesn't complain about anything, `git commit -m "some log message"` (using code markup, please, to make it readable).

Comment: Jaspernetwork:GitHubHelloWorld Jasper$ git pull
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master

Jaspernetwork:GitHubHelloWorld Jasper$ git commit -m "x"
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
Jaspernetwork:GitHubHelloWorld Jasper$ 
sorry i didn't use code markup im not sure how :(

Comment: i have solved the problem - i didn't have the right access rights - ive now used git push (url) and it works - thanks for helping :)